# Cannot connect to GitHub through SSH: host not known

Tags: github, ssh

What is the format for SSH URLs in GitHub?

I'm trying with:

```
ssh git@github.com:Ziiweb/home
```

but I get

> ssh: Could not resolve hostname github.com:Ziiweb/home: Name or service not known

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Github is not accessible by SSH, this is protocol used by git for authentication by SSH Keys, so the command is

```
git clone git@github.com:Ziiweb/home
```

From GitHub docs [Set Up Git](https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git#set-up-git):

> If you use the SSH repository URL (...), SSH keys are used for authentication.

More: [Generating SSH Keys](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys)